# Importing with numpy array with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I would like to know how to import file with multiple delimiter.

I have the following line:

```
"1,000";"2,000";"3,000"
```

How can I import the data with numpy?

I have the following code

```
data=numpy.loadtxt(filepath,delimiter=';')
```

how can I pass a 2nd delimiter for the " "

Kind Regards

Comment: You'll have to parse the quoted strings after loading.

Comment: How so? 
I currently have the following error: could not convert string to float: '(s)'

Comment: add dtype=str to your loadtxt

Comment: It imported the data as a str352. How can I convert it to float?

Comment: I have no idea how setting `dtype=str` is supposed to help. You probably should not do that.

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) can read such a file.  It allows you to control the delimiter and the decimal point character.

Here's my file `delim.dat`:

```
"1,000";"2,000";"3,000"
"5,000";"6,000";"7,000"
"8,000";"9,000";"9,100"
"9,250";"9,500";"9,990"
```

Use the arguments `delimiter=';'` and `decimal=','` in `pandas.read_csv`:

```
In [11]: import pandas as pd

In [12]: df = pd.read_csv('delim.dat', sep=';', decimal=',', header=None)

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
      0    1     2
0  1.00  2.0  3.00
1  5.00  6.0  7.00
2  8.00  9.0  9.10
3  9.25  9.5  9.99
```

---

You can also use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), but you'll have to use the `converters` argument to convert each field from `bytes` to floating point.  For example,

```
In [54]: def myconvert(s):
    ...:     return float(s.strip(b'"').replace(b',', b'.'))
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [55]: a = np.genfromtxt('delim.dat', delimiter=';', converters={k: myconvert for k in range(3)})

In [56]: a
Out[56]: 
array([[1.  , 2.  , 3.  ],
       [5.  , 6.  , 7.  ],
       [8.  , 9.  , 9.1 ],
       [9.25, 9.5 , 9.99]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird delimiters, not to mention the use of commas in the middle of the numeric literals. Numpy isn't set up to handle any of these things by default, so you'll have to parse your input by hand a little bit before you pass it off to Numpy. You can do so using some regular expressions:

```
import re
from io import StringIO

# fake file-like object for demonstration
f = StringIO('''"1,000";"2,000";"3,000"''')

s = re.sub('";?"?', ' ', f.read())
s = re.sub(',', '.', s)

arr = np.fromstring(s, sep=' ')
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[1. 2. 3.]
```

Comment: The comma ',' is a language "barrier". In my contry ',' is used as decimal.

Comment: Gotcha. I changed the answer to match.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Chris. However I would like to do this in numpy/scypy/pandas domain.